# JavaScript error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, html

Apparently when I check whether the class in the console exists, I can reach it. but my browser keeps denying that and gives me this error. I want to have it validated inline like most sign-up forms, I Would appreciate it if you could provide the corrected code too!

codepen file

```
   `https://codepen.io/subhojeet-baroi/pen/BaQYxqN`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function valid(){
  var name = document.forms['form']['name'];
  var email = document.forms['form']['email'];

  var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
  var email_error = document.getElementById('email_error');
  

  if(name.value.length < 9)
  {
    name_error.style.display = "block";
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(email.value.length < 9)
  {
    email_error.style.display = "block";
    email.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, It doesn't work for me. Thanks for commenting, appreciate it!